# combination of linear and exponential

Tags: algebra-precalculus, lambert-w

I am stuck in this question :

If  $a+bx =c^x$ then find $x$ in terms of $a, b$ and $c.$

I have tried certain algorithm but it 
ain't helping 
also a bit by Lambert function but nothing is happening 
please help me with a detailed 
solution 
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are correct thinking about Lambert function.

What you need to do first is to rewrite the equation as $$a+b x=e^{x \log(c)}$$ and then start the manipulations as described in many examples in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

If I am not doing any mistake (please, check all the steps), you whould end  with something looking like $$x=-\frac{a}{b}-\frac{W\left(z\right)}{\log (c)}$$ where $z$ is a function of $b$ and $c$.

I let you finishing the work.

Comment: hey but I am stuck further

Comment: please help me by sending a solution....

Comment: We're here to help you help yourself, not to do everything for you. Where are you stuck? How far do you get? What's the stumbling block?